# text selection toolbar options is not shown on long press EditableText Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use EditableText widget to get user input but text selection toolbar option is not shown on long press. Is it a bug in Flutter?

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: EditableText(
          selectionControls: materialTextSelectionControls,
          maxLines: 5,
          minLines: 1,
          controller: _textEditingController,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          enableInteractiveSelection: true,
          showSelectionHandles: true,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
          backgroundCursorColor: Colors.red,
          cursorColor: Colors.blue,
          selectionColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26, width: 0.5),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(26),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @TinusJackson please check my code.

Comment: Any luck for that facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you change your widget to a `TextField` then the Interactive Selection *(cut, copy, paste, select all)* menu will show to the user on long press. It doesn't seem to work with a `EditableText` widget.

Comment: Thanks. I could use TextField but I think multiple styles are not supported in Textfield.

Comment: What do you mean multiple styles? Your question, or code, didn't mention multiple styles. I would advise you to mark an answer as correct and then ask a new question regarding the styles.

Comment: Multiple styles refers to different styles for each word or character. For example, you can have a look at your answer above, "TextField" and "EditableText" is highlighted which is of different text style than other. I just need to confirm the bug I have mentioned in the question as I already know TextField is not I want to use in my context.

Comment: It does seem like a bug. You might want to open a ticket in GitHub with the Flutter team. If you share with us what you are trying to achieve with your EditableText widget, maybe we can help come up with a different solution.

Comment: Want to show @text as highlighted using EditableText that is working fine but clipboard option not working

Comment: I somehow manage to make it work on double tap on text. I have created custom EditableText widget that extends EditableTextState.

Comment: `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_isKeyboardVisible) {
      return GestureDetector(child: super.build(context), onDoubleTap: () {
        showToolbar();
      });
    }else{
      return super.build(context);
    }
  }`